# Suppose $\forall \epsilon >0$, we have $d(a,b)<\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Take two points $a,b\in X$.

Suppose that for any $\epsilon>0$, I have $d(a,b)<\epsilon$.

It is incredibly obvious to me that $d(a,b)=0$ and hence $a=b$. I am not sure how to explicitly prove this though. Does someone have an idea?

Maybe since $d(a,b)\geq 0$, then we need $d(a,b)=0$ from the above?

Comment: Let $\varepsilon$ goes to $0^+$ in your inequality, you'll find $d(a,b)\leqslant 0$. You can also proceed by contradiction and suppose $d(a,b)\neq 0$ and then taking $\varepsilon:=\frac{d(a,b)}{2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $d(a,b)>0$. Then you can set $\varepsilon=d(a,b)$ in your assumption and get $d(a,b)<d(a,b)$, which is absurd. So $d(a,b)\not>0$, or in other words $d(a,b)\le 0$.

Since, by definition of a metric space, $d(a,b)\ge 0$, the only possibility is that $d(a,b)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is argue why given a real number $a\ge 0$ with the property that for all $\varepsilon >0$ it holds that $a<\varepsilon$, then $a=0$. Do you see why that would imply what you need?

Now, any ideas how to prove that?